# How much overflow in a DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

Is there a way to see *how much* overflow-x there is in a DOM element? It's easy to allow a DOM element to overflow in a certain direction - `overflow:scroll;` is all it takes in CSS. However, is there an easy way to query how overflow there is in a DOM element? Something that comes to mind in jquery might be:

```
var last = $("#foo").last();
var left = last.position().left;
var width = last.width();
// overflows on the right by...
var fooLeft = $("#foo").position().left;
var fooWidth = $("#foo").width();
var fooRight = fooLeft+fooWidth;

var overflowRight = left + width - fooRight
```

Comment: a important question is why do you need to know?

Comment: @madalinivascu it's essential for responsive design

Comment: never heard that, you learn something new every day, can you provide some data to support your claim i will like to know more

Comment: I'm just speaking abstractly here @madalinivascu - responsive design ideally disregards content length. For instance, you could have a gallery website where each exhibit is a block element, but each exhibit has a varying number of photos; which may or may not overflow on the x axis depending on the device size. It would be really useful to show buttons on either side when there _is_ overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a DOM node (`node`), the width of the node is `node.clientWidth`, and the width of the scrollable region is `node.scrollWidth`.

That means that the overflow is the difference between these two numbers:

```
node.scrollWidth - node.clientWidth
```

Comment: @Teemu, wasn't paying enough attention. I've updated the answer, although it should be relatively obvious as to how to get the delta in either dimension.

Comment: I've created a fiddle for it. Hope this helps to test it easily. https://jsfiddle.net/anujverma000/4ye9cg20/1/